# Looking for electronic online proof management system

Tags: web-apps

I am looking for a better way to streamline the proofing process for print files. I am not going to be printing any proofs for the client to see. I also understand that electronic proofs are not an actual representation of the color output.

**What we are doing**

We are currently sending art files through an email attachment and asking for approval

**What we want**

A proof management system where we can upload files in a folder and send a link to a client where they can then comment or mark the files as approved.

**What we would like in this service**

- Import files from DropBox
- Comment system (Where this includes the ability to write over the document with shapes or actually just typing) for files
- Version control for files (This could include side-by-side view of files)
- I would prefer the proof system not be done in flash
- Ability to make folders for clients.

**Services we have already looked at**

- [Proof Hub](https://www.proofhub.com/) We liked that this service can sync with drop box. I like this service but not a big fan of their pricing plan. I would like to see some alternatives.
- [Proof HQ](http://www.proofhq.com/) I didn't really like that this was made with flash.